# Custom Rule in Azure Devops for copying values

Tags: azure-devops

1. I have designed a field named as 'Goal' as a Multi-Line field
   [Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvkqe.png)
2. I have designed a field named as 'Short Goal' as a Single-Line text field
   [Short Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sK7JC.png)

I want to copy values from field 'Goal' to 'Short Goal'.

For this, I have created a Custom Rule as  :
[Custom Rule for Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4H07.png)

But upon saving, I am getting an Error as  : **A value of type Html is not valid for field Short Goal.**

Can anyone please suggest a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

I have followed your steps to configure these two fields and faced the same error message as yours.

It is caused by the field type. Text(multiple lines) is Html format, Text(single line) is string.

[image]

When I create the rule to copy the value from Multi to Multi and from Single to Single, they both work well.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I need to display 'Goal' field in Power BI report and we can't pull multi line field into Power BI. Hence I want to truncate the data and pull 'Short Goal' into Power BI Report.

Comment: Hi, is there any specific reason you need to set "Goal" as Text (Multiple lines)? As far as I know, the way to pass this error message is to copy value from Single to Single, as to be pulled into Power BI Report.